# Select query with where clause in which selecttion is based on the parameter value

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I need to write a query where I am gonna fetch some details from a table, but the problem is the parameter values can be null only 1 parameter value won't be null.

I tried it with following query. I am getting always a result a zero fetch.

P.S I am using hibernate and from there I am firing this query after setting parameters.

```
SELECT count(*)
            FROM audit_details iad
            WHERE
              iad.in_name IN (:inSelected)

             OR

            CASE :callerRef
                  WHEN :callerRef IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                      iad.call_id=:callerRef AND
                  END


            CASE :incReference
                  WHEN :incReference IS NOT NULL
                        THEN
                         iad.abc_id=:incReference
                END 


            CASE :from_date
                WHEN :from_date IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                    Date(iad.abc_update_time)>=Date(:from_date) 
                END


            CASE :to_date
              WHEN :to_date IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                      Date(iad.abc_update_time)<=Date(:to_date)
               END
```

Correct me where and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple Boolean expression:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM audit_details iad
WHERE
    iad.in_name IN (:inSelected)
OR (:callerRef IS NOT NULL AND iad.call_id=:callerRef)
OR (:incReference IS NOT NULL AND iad.abc_id=:incReference)
OR (:from_date IS NOT NULL AND Date(iad.abc_update_time)>=Date(:from_date))
OR (:to_date IS NOT NULL AND Date(iad.abc_update_time)<=Date(:to_date))
```

> What I am doing wrong?

You are using SQL syntax that does not exist.

Comment: won't this give me all the data ??? I just want which is the exact fit to my criteria which I have entered as a user for searching purpose

Comment: @user3679652 The sub-conditions where the corresponding parameter (e.g. `:callerRef`, `:incReference`, etc.) is `null` would be ignored. For example, if `:incReference` is `null`, the `iad.abc_id=:incReference` condition has no effect.

Comment: @user3679652 You are welcome! Try it out, and let me know if it works.